# T-Bone SC450 mic...

Tags: zoom-h4n, home-studio

Have any of you tried this mic? It´s a low cost mic, but I´ve read some good reviews. I´m just recording some voices for a demo project, and can´t afford an expensive mic. I´ve been using the built in mic in the H4, but I guess that this mic could make better takes. If you do know something about it, can it be used with a Zoom H4?  It does need phantom power but the H4 have it, so that should be no problem. I would really appreciate your comments.... GUATEGUAY

Comment: I have no experience with the mic, but if it gets good reviews, within your price range, and something you feel you need, why not just get it?